# What kind of paragraph style settings in InDesign have the effect of CSS' `clear: right` property?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

There's a wonderful property in CSS called `clear` that prevents floating objects from appearing adjacent to something else.  InDesign allows floating objects, but I can't figure out what sort of paragraph style settings to use to prevent objects from floating next to a paragraph.

I have an anchored object floating to the right of my text.  I'd like this anchored object to show up next to my regular paragraphs, but then when a heading comes along, I'd like the heading to slide down below the floating object.

Here's what I have now:

```
 This is some regular paragraph text that  +--------------+
 has an object floating beside it.  The    |              |
 floating object takes up the right side   |    image     |
 of the page for a while.                  |    float     |
                                           |              |
 HEADING                                   |              |
 The heading starts while the floating     +--------------+
 object is still going on.
```

And here's what I'd like:

```
 This is some regular paragraph text that  +--------------+
 has an object floating beside it.  The    |              |
 floating object takes up the right side   |    image     |
 of the page for a while.                  |    float     |
                                           |              |
                                           |              |
                                           +--------------+
 HEADING
 The heading could have started on an earlier row, but it
 didn't, because it's not allowed to appear next to a float-
 ing object.
```

Is there a way to do this with paragraph styles in InDesign?

Comment: Text wrap: `Window > Text Wrap`

Comment: @Scott, I understand applying text wrap to the floating box.  What I'm asking about is what to use for the *heading* paragraph to force it to show up after the end of the floating box.

Comment: Well, you can use the space before in the paragraph options, but I'm not aware of any text setting which would be the equivalent to the "clear" property in CSS.  Generally text wrap is used to alter text flow, not vice versa.

Comment: Do the images fluctuate in height?

Comment: @cclark413, yes, the images vary in height.

Comment: 2 manual methods come to mind: 1. You can use blank frames to block out areas where text shouldn't flow. 2. You could also divide the text frame into two, leaving enough space for the image.  || Both methods are kinda pain in the ass.

Answer (score 4):

My straight forward answer is NO, there is no direct feature out of the box that exists in the Paragraph Styles options.

The problem is that there is no link between Paragraph Styles and Images in the layout!

So what if the image was inline with the text (anchor image)? 
Still the answer is NO.

What if there is a quirky work around? Well I was worried to answer YES, but with some planning I managed to achieve the desired effect. It does though require startup planning, but once you have everything in place then production wise it still works fine for me! I couldn't but share it with all.

So here is the story:

Ingredients:

1. Paragraph styles
2. Object Styles
3. Anchors
4. Spanning knowledge
5. Multi-column text boxes

Directions:

- Create a textbox with multicolumns (based on your grid), mine is 3 columns where the first column on the right is a grid for images.

[image]

- Create 3 Paragraph Styles, (a)Headline (b) Body Copy (c) Body Copy - Images.

[image]
[image]
[image]

- Headline for the headers of each story, Body Copy for the text under the headers that don't have images, Body Copy Images for the text under headers that have images.
- Now run your text and apply the Styles correctly.
- Create your frames for image placements, these will have an Object Style applied with these attributes, Anchor Custom Placement and Text Wrap Jump Object (as shown)

[image]
[image]

- Now cut and paste this frame after the headline of the story that should have this image.

[image]

Let me know!

Comment: One serious flaw is that all the images have to be (text frame width)/(number of columns) wide (give or take column insets and gutter widths)

Comment: True! But for a consistent grid layout this could be a solution. It certainly is limited as mentioned before! Hope it will be useful for someone out there!

Comment: Definitely! :} I'm merely stating a problem in an explicit way