# InDesign: How to have a section head to the left of text?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I'm trying to do the layout below. I was originally trying to create this using 5 columns and having the text span 4 of them. But that didn't work properly because when I would add a column break after the text to go to the next section, it would shift to the next page.

I could do this with separate text boxes, but I really would rather keep this all as one flow across pages. Any ideas? Maybe it's something obvious, but I don't see it. And thanks in advance!

[image: layout sample]

Comment: No, unfortunately you can only manage "marginalia-headlines" with anchored objects. Maybe you want to read this official article on [Adobe InDesign Help](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html) about that.

Comment: Once you travel from a column there is no way back. The only way I believe it works as one text box is by using tables, although a lot of people dont like using them but I think they are very powerful if you know how they work.
I would recommend you to this link on a creative way to use column spans that I suggested to someone when using anchors.
http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30140/what-kind-of-paragraph-style-settings-in-indesign-have-the-effect-of-css-clear/30862#30862